# could not find recipe default for cookbook compat_resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

When I run Chef Client, the following exception is thrown:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.17.44
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["compat_resource", "tomcat"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - compat_resource (12.16.3)
  - tomcat (2.3.4)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe default for cookbook compat_resource

....

Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

What does this message mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO - you didn't really ask a question and rather posted an error message without any further comment. If you want people to help you, take the time and write down a proper question. The error message says that you are referencing a recipe `default` in a cookbook `compat_resource`. So it would be helpful to see more of your code, especially where you reference the cookbook and how your `metadata.rb` and your `Berskfile` looks like (if you have any). Besides: how do you start your Chef client. Provide this information and people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

`compat_resource` cookbook brings the custom resource syntax from Chef 12.5 to earlier Chef 12.X releases. It doesn't have its own recipe. This cookbook is meant to be used for calling resources.

Not sure, what you want to do here.